# How to read escape characters in shell script?

Tags: shell, unix

How to read control c, control z in shell script?

Thanks in advance

added...

What is my requirement was, im deleting a file at the end of script. If the script was stopped (by control c or control z) also i need to delete that file

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: The answers below (by @holygeek and @Jonathan) assume you want to catch the signals generated by C-c and C-z and do something with them in your script?  Is this correct?  If not, and you really want to read them as input, the answers are quite different.  It would help, if you can, to clarify your question.

Comment: What is my requirement was, im deleting a file at the end of script. If the script was stopped (by control c or control z) also i need to delete that file..

Answer (score 1):

Every time an user make control c (or any other special combination) a signal are send to your script.

You will  need to capture this signal in your script using the trap command.

It's long to explain, but this web contain a good explanation about managing signals: http://linuxcommand.org/wss0160.php

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
trap 'echo Hi there' INT USR1 TERM

while true; do sleep 1; done
```

Read `man kill` for the list of allowed signals that you can put there, note the description field in the `SIGNALS` section of the `kill` man page that mentions which signal can be blocked (trapped) by your shell script.

Note: Ctrl + c is the INT (interrupt) signal